8 byte discriminator did not match what was expected when initail PDA account
Get error (8 byte discriminator did not match what was expected)when executing test code. I have checked the Remaining account and the Deserializes account, and both of them pubkey is equal.
Code:
 for warrior_card_usage_ai in &ctx.remaining_accounts[0..warrior_cards_usage_len] {
    if warrior_card_usage_ai.data_is_empty() {
        msg!("creating warrior card usage account");
        let rent_lamports = rent.minimum_balance(warrior_card_usage_data_len);
        let cpi_accounts = CreateAccount {
            from: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
            to: (*warrior_card_usage_ai).clone(),
        };
        let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            cpi_accounts
        );
        // 定义 PDA 的种子数组
        let collect_mint = attacker_cards[0].collection_mint;
        msg!("collect_mint: {}", collect_mint);
        // 使用 find_program_address 计算 PDA 和 bump
        let seeds = &[b"warrior_cards_usage", attacker.as_ref(), collect_mint.as_ref()];

        let (pda, bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(seeds, ctx.program_id);

        msg!("pda: {}, bump: {}", pda, bump);

        let signer_seeds: &[&[u8]] = &[
            b"warrior_cards_usage",
            attacker.as_ref(),
            collect_mint.as_ref(),
            &[bump],
        ];

        // cpi_context.with_signer(&[signer_seeds]);
        msg!("Expected data length: {}", warrior_card_usage_data_len);
        msg!("Minimum rent: {}", rent_lamports);

        create_account(
            cpi_context.with_signer(&[signer_seeds]),
            rent_lamports,
            u64::try_from(warrior_card_usage_data_len).unwrap(),
            ctx.program_id
        )?;
    }
    let mut warrior_cards_usage: Account<WarriorCardsUsage> =
        Account::try_from_unchecked(warrior_card_usage_ai)?;

    msg!("Warrior cards usage: {:?}", warrior_cards_usage.to_account_info().key());
    msg!("Remaining account key: {}", warrior_card_usage_ai.key());

    warrior_cards_usage.attacker = attacker;
    warrior_cards_usage.battle_count = 99;
    warrior_cards_usage.collection_mint = attacker_cards[0].collection_mint;

    msg!("Warrior cards usage: {:?}", warrior_cards_usage);

    warrior_cards_usages.push(warrior_cards_usage);
}


I find the let warrior_card_usage_data_len = mem::size_of::<WarriorCardsUsage>() + 8;
's type is not correct I still have the error when I use the place right type.

Your code has only called create_account on the uninitialized account, but hasn't actually written any data to it yet. So by the time your code calls Account::try_from_unchecked, the account data is still empty, which is why the discriminant check is failing.
If you want to do it quick and dirty, you can just write the discriminant by hand after creating the account, ie:
        create_account(
            cpi_context.with_signer(&[signer_seeds]),
            rent_lamports,
            u64::try_from(warrior_card_usage_data_len).unwrap(),
            ctx.program_id
        )?;
        warrior_card_usage_ai.try_borrow_mut_data()[0..8] = <PUT_DISCRIMINANT_HERE>;

There might be some additional try_into() required, I can't remember how Anchor exposes discriminants exactly. But this should resolve your issue!

It's solved by filling discriminant as mutable.
